# Ensure ChromeDriver closes on force quit

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When running chromeDriver I use a *try/catch/finally* statement to ensure that if any exceptions occur, my WebDriver will close properly. This works perfectly if a exception is thrown, however; in the case that the user force quits my application, the browser instance is not closed. This can lead to built up of unwanted google chrome threads running in the background.

How is it that I can ensure the browser closes when the user force quits my application?

Here is a example of the code:

```
public class WebDriverTest {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    public WebDriverTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverTest main = new WebDriverTest();
        main.test();
    }

    private void test() {
        try {
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
            element.sendKeys("test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //If force quit the browser is never closed
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use driver.close(), it closes currently focused browser window. Then you can call driver.quit() to end driver's session.

Comment: I have tried it with both, the finally chunk does not run because a force quit is the same as a System.exit(0);

Comment: What do you mean by force quit your application. Like close the chrome browser it self or put another url in the browser address bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you seem to be doing the right job, by putting the quit into the finnaly block.

How about you execute this in the end of the test?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM <processname>.exe")
```

So you can kill chromedriver.exe.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure driver's close/quit methods are called on a force shutdown, you can use application's runtime shutdown hook. It's can be registered at a driver's init method and will be called upon any Ctrl-C/other force quit situation. Consider the following snippet.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
  driver.close();
  driver.quit();
}));
```